# Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the following error:

```
./src/index.js Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')
```

I have even written `export default App` at the bottom but still having this issue.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to provide the relevant sections of code so someone can help you better.

Comment: You need to share your code always if possible so that users can get better understanding of your problem